# Write excel sheet in Selenium using row.getlastcellnum() method in for loop causes java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, selenium, apache-poi

Below is my selenium code to write data in first empty column in excel sheet:

```
public void setAllData(int sheetNumber)
    {
        sheet1 = wb.getSheetAt(sheetNumber);
        for(int i = 0; i<rowCount+1; i++)
        {
            row = sheet1.getRow(i);
            **int k = row.getLastCellNum();**
            **for(int j = row.getLastCellNum(); j<row.getLastCellNum()+1; j++)**
            **//for(int j = row.getLastCellNum(); j<k+1; j++)**
            {
                sheet1.getRow(i).createCell(j).setCellValue("Pass");
            }
        }
        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
            wb.write(fos);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        } 
    }
```

When I used for-loop using `j<row.getLastCellNum()+1` following error is coming: "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid column index (16384).  Allowable column range for EXCEL2007 is (0..16383) or ('A'..'XFD')"

Where as if I store the `row.getLastCellNum()` value in a variable (k) and then used that variable in for-loop, its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

getLastCellNum()

will return total rows PLUS ONE.

See [API](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFRow.html#getLastCellNum%28%29)